# Why would async function pass an empty object in request body?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using `nuxt.js, mongoDB, express and bodyParser, too`

*So the other answers here won't help me for they say having bodyParser will fix it*.

The uploadPet function is supposed to gather the form data, and send it to api as a post request. Appending formData is a success, this i can check in console, but then somehow in api.js the request is an empty object.

**new.vue**:

```
async uploadPet() {
  let formData = new FormData();   

  for (let data in this.pet) {
    formData.append(data, this.pet[data]);
  }
  for (var p of formData) {
      console.log(p);
    }
  try {
    console.log('trying to make a post request: ' + formData)
    let response = await fetch("http://localhost:9000/api/pet/new", {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData
    });
    this.$router.push("/");
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}
```

**api.js**: (by now the request body has no data)

```
    router.post('/pet/new', (req, res) => {
    console.log('posting!')
    console.log(req.body.name)
    Pet.create({
        name: req.body.name,
        description: req.body.description
    }, (err, pet) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log('CREATE error: ' + err);
                res.status(500).send('Error')
            } else {
                res.status(200).json(pet)
            }
        })
    })
```

**index.js**:

```
    const express = require('express');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const mongoose = require('mongoose') 
    const morgan = require('morgan');
    const api = require('./routes/api')
    const pets = require('./mock')
    const path = require('path');
    const app = express()

    app.use((req, res, next) => {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested- 
           With, Content-Type, Accept");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, 
            DELETE, OPTIONS");
        next();
    })
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

**I already do have bodyparser concerning lines please don't recommend me that**:

Comment: Where is your body-parser middleware that would process the incoming form data on the server?  You claim to know about that, but don't show that in the code you've shown so far.  If that middleware is not properly installed, then `req.body` will just be an empty object (as it appears to be).

Answer (score 0):

use this code in app.js because you don't parse req.body

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```